# Customizing the built in WorkbenchAction

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I just started working on a project using RCP. And in its "about" section, it uses 
the built in WorkbenchAction:

```
IWorkbenchAction actionAbout = ActionFactory.ABOUT.create(window);
actionAbout.setText(Messages.ABOUT);
itemAbout = new ActionContributionItem(actionAbout);
```

However, I need to add a tab in that popup and I'm not finding any way to customize
it. Is this something possible or should look for another way to do things?

Comment: What do you mean by Tab? Do you mean the row of image buttons showing the installed features?

Comment: yes, a tab within "Details of the install", along with plug-ins and configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.installationPages` extension point to add a tab to the Installation Details tabs.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.installationPages"> 
   <page
        name="XYZ Info"
        class="package.XYZInstallInfoPage"
        id="plugin.xyz>
   </page>
</extension>
```

Your class must extends `org.eclipse.ui.about.InstallationPage`

For more details see the [help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_installationPages.html)